# One word for the feeling of comfort talking to a friend

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I feel very comfortable and frank while sharing my personal stuff like issues/likes/dislikes/experiences to one of my friends. Being with that one friend is comfortable.

1. How do I describe this feeling in one word?
2. What word would be appropriate (except for **comfortable** and **frank**) if I were to tell that friend that:

   > "I feel very ___________ talking to you!"

I wanted to express my this feeling to my friend.

**Edit**: So to be exact, my question is how should I put this in more better words:-

> "I feel very comfortable with you!"

Comment: This is a perfect situation to use a thesaurus to first look up alternatives before asking here. If you show the references you've consulted, and what other words you're not looking for, people answering won't be redoing your work (or doing it for you in the first place). Check out some online thesauruses, add some research you've done, and you'll have a much better question.

Comment: To Katherine's point, checking a thesaurus immediately yeilded *console*, *commiserate*, *solace*, offer *condolences* and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"Feel comfortable" is a good choice, "feel ***[at ease](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+ease)***'  is an alternative expression you may use:

> - relaxed and comfortable: *The girl behind the bar was completely at ease, chatting with her customers as she mixed their drinks.*

- I feel at ease talking to you....

Consider also the expression "to ***[open up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/open+up)***". You are more  likely to open up with a friend:

> - (about someone or something) (with someone) and open up (on someone or something) (with someone) ***to speak freely about someone or something;***  to speak a great deal about someone or something.
>
>   - *After a while, he began to open up about his disagreements. He opened up with us about the accident. She opened up on Fred with Alice*.

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered '[simpatico](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simpatico)'? (MW, definition 2)

> being on the same wavelength, congenial, sympathetic

It describes the relationship more than it does the person - someone who's simpatico for you may not be simpatico for me.

> I find Nancy very simpatico; I feel like I can talk with her about anything.

Comment: What's with the drive-by down votes?